# Update one single column in database using JPQL

Tags: java, jpa

How to write a JPQL query to update a single column in MySql DB :

Regular SQL update query :

`Update NATAddress SET ordinal = ? WHERE ordinal = ? AND natId = ?`

JPQL update query :

`UPDATE NATAddress na SET na.ordinal = ?1 WHERE na.ordinal = ?2 AND na.networkDomain.natId =?3`

Eclipse shows following error for above JPQL update query

`Input parameters can only be used in the WHERE clause or HAVING clause of a query.`

Looks like JPA specifications doesn't allow to set input parameters in update columns.
Is there any other way to update other than updating the whole JPA Entity using merge() method?

Comment: Could you show the method and.annotations?

Answer (score 0):

Update your query to be like this I assume this is the Class name and this is the name of its attributes

```
UPDATE NATAddress na SET na.ordinal = ? WHERE na.ordinal = ? AND na.networkDomain.natId =?
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String query = "Update NATAddress SET ordinal = '"+Parameter1+"' WHERE ordinal = '"+Parameter2+"' AND natId = '"+Parameter3+"'";
```

Comment: Where parameter1, parameter2 and parameter3 are variables

Comment: I have written a generic method to perform CRUD operations through JPA which uses ordinal parameters, so I cannot use named parameters here.

Comment: You can pass parameters to generic method too and these parameters will also used in query to make perform parameterized Query

Comment: Coder1 am talking about ordinal parameters which I'm already passing to generic JPA update method. So named parameters are not useful in my case. Also I doubt if JPA specification allows passing parameters to only WHERE and HAVING clause - then it will not allow named parameter as well.

Comment: It would be help if you show method, where these all problem take place